# Struts2 Form Fields are submitted as request attributes in action

Tags: struts2

Why Form fields for a model drive Struts2 action are added as request attributes? I am able to retrieve them both as request.getAttribute and request.getParameter in my action.

Comment: Yes, you can. But generally you want to use those attributes inside an entity. So, ModelDriven provides a way to map all request attributes based on your entity's attribute names.